# How do you pip install to a specific version of Anaconda Python stored on a usb?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, portability, usb-flash-drive

I have an anaconda package installed on my pc as well as on a usb. I want to add some modules to the anaconda that's on the usb. How do I do this without it installing them onto my pc version?

Comment: Call out the specific version of pip that you want to use: `USB_DRIVE_LETTER:\Anaconda_Install_Directory\Scripts\pip.exe install package-name` I think that should work